# Stuck at training model with CPU

Tags: tensorflow-serving

As the example points out:

```sh
docker run -it -p 8500:8500 --gpus all tensorflow/serving:latest-devel
```

should train the mnist mode, however I want to use intel cpu for training, not gpu. But no luck, it stucked at `Training model...`

Here is the command I used:

```sh
docker run -it -p 8500:8500 tensorflow/serving:latest-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it will download resources at first, which a proxy is needed sometimes.